# How did Corinne's car end up abandoned, and how did her earring end up on the backseat?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-stranger

In *The Stranger*, a series on Netflix, there is a scene in episode 6, at 13:20 where Johanna tells Adam "Your wife's car has been found up by the airport."

At 15:40, they find the car abandoned by the side of the road.

[image]

Johanna says to Adam ""And did you or she ever park here when using the airport?". He says "No, never." And then, "Maybe she ran out of charge."

Johanna then looks inside the immaculate car and finds an earring on the back seat. Adam recognises it as Corinne's that she never takes off.

[image]

[image]

We assume something happened, but at this point

> she was murdered and buried by Doug Tripp.

There is no mention of the use of her car in the final reveal at the end so how did it end up here, why was it stranded, and why was one of Corinne's earrings found on the backseat?

Answer (score 1):

The answers (such as there are) are to be found in the final reveal. My own transcription of episode 8, from around 0:35:30

> Tripp: You go to the police and what will they know? Corinne faked her
> pregnancy. Fact. You two had a fight. Fact. The next day she was
> killed in the garage. Fact. [...] And the logical conclusion? You
> killed her. You buried her. You parked her car near the airport.

Accompanied by a flashback to the earring being found on the back seat, then Adam seeing that Corinne's body lacks that earring.

> Tripp: Hid her phone to make it look like suicide.

Accompanied by a flashback to Adam and the boys finding the phone on top of the viaduct, while Tripp (we are only now shown) is secretly watching from cover.

We can then infer that it was in fact *Tripp* that performed both these last two actions, in order to set up the framing of Adam, although it's not clear exactly when he moved the car - the fact that it's 'immaculate' suggests it wasn't used to move the body, so he must have done something like:

- Kill Corinne in the garage
- Move the body to the woods in an unknown vehicle, unobserved
- Recover the earring
- Obtain Corinne's car key (maybe Corinne had it on her person, although she was at home so this seems unlikely)
- Plant the earring
- Move the car while leaving no forensic evidence